# Android UX- Navigation Drawer vs Main Screen

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, submenu, user-experience

I am designing android app in which I have some **categories** and **sub-category**.

**What I am doing?**

In first image I have placed category menu item with sub-category menu item in Navigation Drawer. Sub menu will appear when user click on menu item. it's kind of drop down type menu.
[image]

In this second image Navigation Drawer is closed. Here problem is that when user click on category grid item.He will redirect to gridview which include all the item of that root category. So **he will not redirect to any subcategory type hierarchy. If user wants to go through category by subcategory then he have to use Navigation drawer where subcategory will appear to him.**
[image]

**Note**: some category don't have any subcategory.

**Question?**

1) Is it proper navigation type for better UX?

2) Any other better way for doing this thing which make UX more better?

Answer (score 0):

You Need To Use Expandable List View Instead of Simple List View In Your Layout...
Just Try this Suggestion and Tell me...
best Of Luck..

Comment: Thank you for fast reply. But my problem is not about expandable listview but it's about User Experience. I edited my question please see bold line. Looking for your answer :)